# How can I design a double pole eight throw microwave (2-6 GHz) switch?

Tags: rf, switches, electromagnetic, microwave, vna

I need to design a DP8T microwave switch for a microwave imaging senior design project. The frequency range is 2 to 6 GHz.

I need to switch between 8 antennas and a 2 port VNA. So each antenna transmitting and receive one at a time. I'd imagine this is a common problem in RF engineering, but I can not find an IC chip or a commercial solution that is 2X8.

Switching time: Doesn't matter

Power: 16 dBm

Insertion Loss ~ .8 dB

Isolation > 30 dB

Control signal: TTL or CMOS

Above all, I will settle for anything that can work. I want to have a start at something even if I can improve later. My budget is very limited, even though I have access to PCB printing and lab equipment.

Comment: Power, switching time, acceptable loss, reflective or absorbing???

Comment: To be clear, you really need to design one? Or do you just need to include one in your system?

Comment: Generally, you can't if you have to ask here

Comment: Go on the perregrine semiconductor site, psemi.com, and select from their catalogue of fine switches. You wouldn't design a CPU, or an engine, you'd buy. At 6 GHz, buy. You'll have plenty of 'design' to do keeping your line impedances nice (hint use Rogers 4350, not FR4, for an easy life, it processes like and can be multi-layered with FR4). Full disclosure - I have no financial interest in Peregrine or Rogers at all, but when I worked professionally, my microwave designs were littered with the things.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be thinking about using pin diodes to act as multiplexers. Here's one that might be useful: -

[image]

There are plenty of internet articles that describe how pin diodes are used for this type of application.

Comment: Imagine it was plain ordinary signals (not especially RF) and draw a switch arrangement that would be ok for (say) audio and embed this into your question. Message me when you have done this.